# Startup Applications refuses to launch a simple, executable script

Tags: 13.04, vpn, autostart

Screenshots of some relevant information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to run a bash script at login, so I put it in Startup Applications. There is no configuration besides calling "xterm -e autovpn" that works.

Here's the thing: it worked just fine on 32-bit Ubuntu 13.04. I upgraded with a fresh install 3 days ago, and now I'm manually calling a script that used to autorun like a champ.

I've been working this issue for hours over the course of several days. Google tells me nothing.

Here's a copy of what's in .config/autostart:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=autovpn
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=AutoVPN
Name=AutoVPN
Comment[en_US]=Connect automatically to VPN.
Comment=Connect automatically to VPN.
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Have you tried using the full path?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put pause before the nmcli command, the necessary networking services probably not running in  time of execution.

Add this: `sleep 5` into your shell script for wait for 5 seconds